# Javascript - next button for image gallery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple gallery for my website, I need to display an image thumbnail and a table side by side but I've got problems with the next button!
I'm working on the image atm, but when I press next button it opens the image in a new windows, like if I clicked on the thumbnail!
What's wrong?

```
<body>
<div id="page"> 
    <div id="header">
        <div class="title">title</div>
     </div>
<div class="menu-wrap" style="position:relative; z-index:9999">    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
              <li><a href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="pageContent">
    <div class="articleContent">
      <div class="articleTitle">L'esterno della Cattedrale</div>

         <div class="item-page"  >
         <a href="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" target="_blank"><img id="immagine" src="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="A"/></div>
<div id="tabella" style='float:left'><p> prova2</p></div>

    <br><div class='button' onclick="next()">Next</div>

                         </div>
    </div>


    </div>

</div>
    <div id="footer"></div>

    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
  effect:'fade',
  pauseTime: 5000
  });
});


function next() {
var text = "";
var image = "";

var image = document.getElementById("immagine").getAttribute('data-value');
   //alert(image);
switch(image) {
case "A":
    text = "2";
    image=' <a href="images/esterno/esterno02.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/esterno/esterno02.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="B"/>';
    break;
case "B":
    text = "3";
    image=' <a href="images/esterno/esterno03.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/esterno/esterno03.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="C"/>';
    break;
case "C":
    text = "4";
    image=' <a href="images/esterno/esterno04.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/esterno/esterno04.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="D"/>';
    break;

default:
    text = "default";
}
document.getElementById("immagine").innerHTML = image;
document.getElementById("tabella").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing closing `</a>` tag. Since it's not closing, it is clicked when you click on "Next".

Change

```
<div class="item-page"><a href="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" target="_blank"><img id="immagine" src="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="A"/></div>
```

to

```
<div class="item-page"><a href="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" target="_blank"><img id="immagine" src="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" height="50" width="50" style="margin-left:15%;margin-top:5%" data-value="A"/></a></div>
```